# split pandas dataframe to list of dataframes based on column value difference

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to split pandas dataframe to list of dataframes in which  value difference between FIRST row value of 'address' column and LAST row value is not greater than 100

What i do now is iterate over the dataframe rows to find the row where to split

```
import pandas as pd


def split_df(vars_df):
    lis = []
    dif = vars_df['address'].iloc[0]
    for ids, df_variable in vars_df.iterrows():
        address_dif = df_variable.address - dif
        if address_dif > 100:
            lis.append(vars_df[vars_df['address'] < df_variable.address])
            rest = split_df(vars_df[vars_df['address'] >= df_variable.address])
            if isinstance(rest, list):
                for element in rest:
                    lis.append(element)
            else:
                lis.append(rest)

            break
    if len(lis) == 0:
        lis = vars_df
    return lis


d = {'address': [1, 105, 21, 229], 'val': [3, 4, 12, 100]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

df.sort_values('address', inplace=True)
print(split_df(df))
```

Is there a better solution than iterating over the dataframe rows and appending to list